# tf tree slam and base link

Tags: moveit, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use a quadrotor with ROS moveit! The driver node of the quadrotor publishes a tf tree, which contains odom, base, frontcam and bottomcam, where odom is the parent frame of base and base is the parent frame of frontcam and bottom cam. Besides this diver I am running a Slam algorithm, which publishes another tf tree, which contains two frames, map and sensor.

When setting up moveit with a urdf model, I create a virtual link between the map frame from the slam algorithm and the base link of the quadrotor. When I launch the resulting demo.launch I get the following warn messages:

```
[ WARN] [1448659454.360465559]: Unable to transform object from frame 'ardrone_base_frontcam' to planning frame 'Map' (Could not find a connection between 'Map' and 'ardrone_base_frontcam' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.) 
[ WARN] [1448659454.360597000]: Unable to transform object from frame 'ardrone_base_link' to planning frame 'Map' (Could not find a connection between 'Map' and 'ardrone_base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.) 
[ WARN] [1448659454.360687375]: Unable to transform object from frame 'ardrone_base_bottomcam' to planning frame 'Map' (Could not find a connection between 'Map' and 'ardrone_base_bottomcam' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.) 
[ WARN] [1448659454.360741781]: No transform available between frame 'odom' and planning frame 'Map' (Could not find a connection between 'Map' and 'odom' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.)
```

Apparently I need to publish transforms to connect the trees and have only one. I see the following problem: on one tree odometry is being published from the IMU. I am not interested in this data, I only wish to represent the pose of the urdf model in rviz with the data from the Slam algorithm. I would like the base of the quadrotor to share the pose output from the sensor frame.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT1: I cannot provide the tf frames right now because I do not have the quadrotor with me, for now, I can give a brief explanation of this. I am using visual slam Ptam so in one tree I have map and sensor, where map is the fixed frame. In the other tf tree I have odom followed by base and the two children of base are frontcam and bottomcam. In this post ( [http://answers.ros.org/question/216826/robot_localization-tf-tree-structure/]  I read that there would have to be a static transform between world and odom. I have found no files for parameter configuration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221639/tf-tree-slam-and-base-link/) by [Lolita390](https://answers.ros.org/users/24989/lolita390/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paul3333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68392/paul3333/) on 2021-03-04**:
@Lolita390 where you able to solve your problem? Im facing the exact same issue right now.

Would be great if you could share your solution!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-06**:
Please don't use an *answer* to leave a *comment*. This isn't a forum

**Comment by [paul3333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68392/paul3333/) on 2021-03-08**:
Sorry about that.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-09**:
No worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fact, your slam node should broadcast transformation from `map` to `odom`. It seems missing.

It may be helpful if you can post the screenshot of `rosrun tf view_frames` output and your content of launch files with any relevant parameter (or .yaml) files.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lolita390](https://answers.ros.org/users/24989/lolita390/) on 2015-11-28**:
I replied in EDIT1.